# I Want to Upload an image to my facebook account using my own J2ME application, without eSWT and LWUIT

Tags: java-me

I Want to Upload an image to my face book account using my own J2ME application, without eSWT and LWUIT. for this i have got application Id and secret code from face book developers but i really unable to use them Please help me how to do it. THANKS

Answer (score 0):

Have you read facebook documentation?

It says you should obtain session if it's not a web application.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/photos.upload/